# Scroll / Zoom a pixi.js canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, webgl, pixi.js

Below is an easy way to put some text on a pixi.js (using WebGL) canvas.

**How can we scroll / zoom the displayed part of the canvas ?**
(i.e. mouse down + drag should move ...)

Example of what I would like to achieve :  http://s419743653.onlinehome.fr/things/test2.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>pixi.js example 1</title>
    <script src="pixi.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    var stage = new PIXI.Stage(0xFFFFFF);
    var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(800, 600);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);
    var text = new PIXI.Text("Hello World", {font:"50px Arial", fill:"black"});
  stage.addChild(text);
  renderer.render(stage);   
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

set the scale property on the `DisplayObjectContainer`. In your case you don't have any so you can scale the stage.

```
stage.scale.x = 2;
stage.scale.y = 2;
```

or you can put your objects in a group and scale the group.

```
var group = new Pixi.DisplayObjectContainer();
group.scale.x = 2;
group.scale.y = 2;

group.add(text);
```

Comment: thanks for the zooming part ! How can we scroll / move north/south/east/west ?
As I'm really new to pixi.js (and even not very used to js anyway), could you paste these lines in this : http://jsbin.com/sedegedufenu/1/edit ? (for example with ZOOM+ ZOOM- buttons)  So I'll know where to do these things !

Comment: I used `stage.scale` as you explained, and I change the `scale` each time the ZOOM+/ZOOM- buttons are pressed, but it doesn't seem to work : http://jsbin.com/wegahiqegaha/2/edit
Any idea ?

Comment: @Basj `stage.scale` doesn't work, use a `DisplayObjectContainer` see [here](http://jsbin.com/temopa/1/), for scrolling, just set the x and y values accordingly.

Comment: thanks @user3995789. It works indeed with a `DisplayObjectContainer`. But something else : I expected that when zooming, the text wouldn't be blurry, I expected everything to be vector instead of bitmap... But look at the result (zoom factor 12) : http://jsbin.com/qeqoneselelo/1/.  The text is very blurry...  Do you have an idea (to be able to zoom with no blur/pixelisation) ?

In this example : http://s419743653.onlinehome.fr/things/test2.htm, the text doesn't get blurry when zooming!

Comment: @Basj Pixi has various scaling modes, this would get rid of some blur `PIXI.scaleModes.DEFAULT = PIXI.scaleModes.NEAREST;`, check out the documentation for more options, that's the best I could come up. check out these related links as well. [blurry text](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/2209-blurry-text-using-custom-font/), [resize screen](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/3108-resize-screen-in-pixel-art-pixijs/).